# Vaadin using JavaScriptComponentConnector not the expected MyApplicationConnector

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, vaadin, vaadin7

My Vaadin application is integrated with a javascript, I'am having some NoLayout problems with it.

I debugged into the vaadin code and found out that ApplicationConnection class do some magic in updateConnectorState() method checking for NoLayout annotation.

I noticed at this place in the code, the connector object is JavaScriptComponentConnector not the one that is expected MyApplicationConnector that in turns leading to incorrect state class (JavaScriptComponentState instead of MyApplicationState class).

I'm bit frustrating with this problems since it's happening in the vaadin classes and I cannot do much in it. I also posted a question on vaadin forum but no one replied :-(

Any suggestions/help would be a great help, please.

Comment: How did you specify it to use your connector instead of the default one?

Comment: @AndréSchild, I did not specify anything related to connectors, it's already there and using the default one (for Javascript it's JavaScriptComponentConnector). JavaScriptComponentConnector has state as JavaScriptComponentState and this state object doesn't have my properties in it and that's why it's throwing NoLayout error. In fact, MyApplicationState class that extends JavaScriptComponentState has these properties but vaadin is searching those in JavsScriptComponentState class not in MyApplicationState.  I hope could clear the problem. please help.